# Ocaml `new` keyword

Tags: ocaml

In some code I'm looking at uses:

```
Lwt_engine.set (new Lwt_engine.libev ())
```

What does the keyword `new` mean in this context?

I presume it is something to do with the object system?

Comment: You are creating a new instance of the class libev in the module  Lwt_engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, `Lwt_engine.libev` is a class. Calling `new Lwt_engine.libev ()` creates a new object in that class.